# Ransack search and sorting not working with some attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, spree, ransack

Ransack search work fine with some attributes:

```
Spree::Callback.all.ransack(name_cont: 1).result

SELECT "spree_callbacks".* FROM "spree_callbacks" WHERE ("spree_callbacks"."name" ILIKE '%1%')
```

And don't work with others...

```
Spree::Callback.all.ransack(phone_cont: 1).result

SELECT "spree_callbacks".* FROM "spree_callbacks"
```

What's wrong?

P.S. Callback is my custom model under Spree module

And example of Callback object:

```
Spree::Callback.first
  Spree::Callback Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "spree_callbacks".* FROM "spree_callbacks"  ORDER BY "spree_callbacks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Spree::Callback:0x00000009eb68c0 id: 39, 
phone: "123", 
comment: "", 
created_at: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 03:37:03 UTC +00:00, 
updated_at: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 03:41:34 UTC +00:00, 
name: "123", 
processed: true>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nuT707 - To be able to search by using ransack gem, you will first have to whitelist all those fields on which you wanna perform search.
So in you `callback.rb` model add the following line -

`self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes |= %w[phone]`

and now try to search with ransack.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes ||= %w[phone]`

Comment: Hi @nuT707

`self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes |= %w[phone]` This will add `phone` to whitelisted array only if it is not present before in array.
`|` this ruby OR operator
Ex. a= [1,2,3]
a |= [2,4] => [1,2,4]

Where as you have used memoization here.
`||=` is user for memoization
Ex. a=[1,2,3]
a||=[2,4] => [1,2,3]

Comment: I receive **true**, not array

Comment: `self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes = %w[phone]` works fine